# how to give the accurate path to find the remote actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-remote-actor

I am following this tutorial

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-akka-actors-remote-example

I am following it as it is but my program is not running it gives me errors and i am confused about this line :

```
val remote = context.actorFor("akka://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/RemoteActor")
```

What do i have to write in place of "user" ? When I write the full path to the end for example:

```
 val remote = context.actorFor("akka://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/sw/opt/programs/akka/akkaremoting/RemoteActor")
```

and run both hellolocal and helloremote both give me errors about looking up the actor for that address.

and if i write the code as it is it gives me error 
helloremote erros :

```
[INFO] [10/27/2014 16:06:23.736] [HelloRemoteSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/user/RemoteActor#911921687] to Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
^Csarawaheed@ubuntu:/opt/ifkaar/programs/akka/akkaremoting/helloremote$ sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /opt/ifkaar/programs/akka/akkaremoting/helloremote/project
[info] Set current project to helloremote (in build file:/opt/ifkaar/programs/akka/akkaremoting/helloremote/)
[info] Running HelloRemote 
Remote Actor receive messgage : The remote actor is alive  
[INFO] [10/27/2014 17:24:06.136] [HelloRemoteSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/user/RemoteActor#-792263999] to Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

hellolocal erros :

```
[INFO] [10/27/2014 16:06:23.736] [HelloRemoteSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/user/RemoteActor#911921687] to Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
^Csarawaheed@ubuntu:/opt/ifkaar/programs/akka/akkaremoting/helloremote$ sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /opt/ifkaar/programs/akka/akkaremoting/helloremote/project
[info] Set current project to helloremote (in build file:/opt/ifkaar/programs/akka/akkaremoting/helloremote/)
[info] Running HelloRemote 
Remote Actor receive messgage : The remote actor is alive  
[INFO] [10/27/2014 17:24:06.136] [HelloRemoteSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/user/RemoteActor#-792263999] to Actor[akka://HelloRemoteSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An remote akka actor path is made up of the following components:

```
protocol:actor system name:server address:remoting port:root path:actor path + name
```

So for the first example, those components end up being:

```
protocol = akka://
actor system name = HelloRemoteSystem
server address = 127.0.0.1
remoting port = 5150
root path: user
actor path + name = RemoteActor
```

All actors started by you in your custom actor code will roll up under the `user` root.  Akka uses another root called `system` for system level actors.  These actors fall under a separate hierarchy and supervision scheme from the custom ones that a user needs for their custom application.  So `user` should always be part of the path to the custom `RemoteActor` from the example.  Then, because `RemoteActor` is started as a top level actor (no direct supervisor, started from `system` as opposed to the `context` of another actor) with a `name = "RemoteActor"` it will roll up under the path `/user/RemoteActor`.  So putting it all together, the path to use to remotely lookup that actor is the one given in the example code:

```
"akka://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/RemoteActor"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change "user"

If you look inside the documentation of [akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/general/addressing.html) you see that "user" is a subdirectory of each actor system that contains all user-related/user-created actors, it's not the name of your user :)